# Remove non printable white spaces from unknown (to me) encoding

Tags: regex, xml, r, encoding

So I've parsed some XML file using the [r](/questions/tagged/r) `XML` package using the following code

```
library(XML) 
data <- xmlToDataFrame(xmlParse("Some file I can't share.xml"))
```

Everything worked fine and I've got the expected result

```
dim(data)
## [1] 554560 13
```

The only problem though that some of my entries looks as follows

```
x <- "2  irfl014"
x
## [1] "2  \002\003\004\003\005\005\006\005\002\003\004\003\005\005\006\005irfl014"
```

Tried to identify the encoding (with no success)

```
Encoding(x)
## [1] "unknown"

library(stringi)
stri_enc_detect(x)
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$Encoding
# [1] "UTF-8"     "Shift_JIS" "GB18030"   "EUC-JP"    "EUC-KR"    "Big5"     
# 
# [[1]]$Language
# [1] ""   "ja" "zh" "ja" "ko" "zh"
# 
# [[1]]$Confidence
# [1] 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1
```

Encoding isn't my strongest field of expertise, is there any simple way to convert `x` to simply

```
x
## [1] "2  irfl014"
```

Comment: Can you provide a `dput` of `x`?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein I've already shared the `dput`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
x <- "2  \002\003\004\003\005\005\006\005\002\003\004\003\005\005\006\005irfl014"

cat(x)
# 2  irfl014
```

The special characters, e.g., `"\002"` are non-printable *control characters*. See [here](http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html) for more information.

You can use the following `gsub` command to remove all control characters:

```
gsub("[[:cntrl:]]+", "", x)
# [1] "2  irfl014"
```