# trimws bug? leading whitespace not removed

Tags: r, trim

***Edit***: Thanks to **R Yoda**, I was finally able to create a reproducible example to the issue I am facing:

```
x = rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xa0, 0x31, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x33, 0x32, 0x35, 0x39, 0x32)))
trimws(x)
```

=> Question: How can I trim x?

***Old text of the question:***
Please see attached screenshot. Unfortunately I am not able to create reproducible example as `dput` is affecting the result...

As anyone an idea how to investigate what's going wrong with x? The leading whitespace doesn't seem to be a standard one!

[image]

`charToRaw(x)` gives a0 31 31 2e 31 33 32 35 39 32
`dput(charToRaw(x))` gives `as.raw(c(0xa0, 0x31, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x33, 0x32, 0x35, 0x39, 
0x32))`
`Encoding(x)` gives `"unknown"` (same as `Encoding(" 11.132592")`)

Comment: Not able to reproduce the problem `x <- " 11.132592";
trimws(x)#
[1] "11.132592"` in `R 3.4.0`

Comment: @akrun I know, frustrating! I have the same as you in my R `3.3.2`. How can I investigate why is x different from its value in `dput` ?

Comment: so which R version is having this problem

Comment: What is the encoding of x?

Comment: Please include the output of `dput(x)` in your question. That will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: @akrun, R 3.2.2 for sure. But your code doesn't reproduce the bug. Check my screenshot: x ``gives`` "11.132592", but is now defined like this.

Comment: @Jaap I know this link to reproducible code. Please check the content of my screenshot. `dput(x)` gives " 11.132592". But this bug is not reproducible with `dput` because `trimws(x)` and `trimws(" 11.132592")` return different values....

Comment: Could be an encoding problem... If you cannot use `dput` (why?) please post at least the output of `charToRaw(x)` and `Encoding(x)` here maybe this shows the reason...

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433056/remove-non-printable-white-spaces-from-unknown-to-me-encoding

Comment: `charToRaw(' ')` results in `20` while the first character of `x` is `a0`; it is probably therefore not recognized as a space

Comment: @Jaap how can I transform `a0` into `20` ? or trim `20` characters?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`0xa0` is encoding another type of space (the non-breaking space) in `R`, while `0x20` is the white space.
`trimws` searches for white spaces or tabs or linebreaks or carriage returns (represented by `[ \t\r\n]+`) but not for non-breaking spaces, hence it does not work.
You can use `sub` (to suppress either leading or trailing spaces) or `gsub` (to suppress both trailing and leading spaces) to remove any kind of trailing or leading space(s) (including the one represented by `0xa0`):

```
sub("^\\s+", "", x)
[1] "11.132592"
```

And for removing leading and trailing spaces:

```
gsub("(^\\s+)|(\\s+$)", "", x)
```

Comment: Thank you! For the record `stringr::str_trim` also works great

Comment: @RockScience there is a `C` routine under `stringr::str_trim`, which I didn't check but I'm guessing it removes any knid of space, contrary to `trimws` ;-)

Comment: Future readers who come here and above `gsub` solution does not work due to carriage + line break space (`0xc2 0xa0`), see this [perl regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43734965/1422451) or this [remove all/any space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27237551/1422451).

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is replace the wrongly encoded spaces with the right ones:

```
trimws(rawToChar(replace(x1, x1 == as.raw(0xa0), as.raw(0x20))))
```

which gives:

> ```
> [1] "11.132592"
> ```

For conversion to numeric, just wrap above code in `as.numeric`.

---

Used data:

```
x1 <- as.raw(c(0xa0, 0x31, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x33, 0x32, 0x35, 0x39, 0x32))
```

Comment: unfortunately that's not triming. it creates issue if the space is in the middle of the string.

Comment: @RockScience this answers the question that was asked. If you didn't ask the right question, that's on you.