# Trim a string that has control character whitespace

Tags: r, trim

```
x = rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xa0, 0x31, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x33, 0x32, 0x35, 0x39, 0x32)))
trimws(x) # this doesn't trim it!
```

How can I trim *x* or any similar string that has leading and/or trailing whitespace that are not trimmed by *trimws*?

**Disclosure:** this question is the continuation of [trimws bug? leading whitespace not removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45050617/trimws-bug-leading-whitespace-not-removed/45051137#45051137) but I was asked to create a separate question.

Edit: 
here is a suggested code, any more elegant solution would be welcomed

```
trimws2 = function(x) {
        sapply(x, FUN=function(x) {
          xraw = charToRaw(x)
          xraw[xraw==as.raw(0xa0)]=charToRaw(" ")
          trimws(rawToChar(xraw))
        })
      }
trimws2(x)
```

Comment: Your `x`gives me this : `[1] " 11.132592"`, you want to remove the space in front of the value ?

Comment: @MbrMbr yes. But `trimws` doesn't work on my x. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45050617/trimws-bug-leading-whitespace-not-removed/45051137#45051137

Comment: @RockScience Did you try `str_trim` from the package `stringr` ? With my version of R (3.3.3), it returns : `[1] "11.132592"`

Comment: @MbrMbr if you want to add this as answer, i will accept it asap. Thanks

Comment: You weren't asked a separate question. @HongOoi said you didn't formulate your question well; which means you have to reformulate your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str_trim` from `stringr` package.

Data :

```
> x = rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xa0, 0x31, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x33, 0x32, 0x35, 0x39, 0x32)))
> x
[1] " 11.132592"
```

and just write :

```
library(stringr)

str_trim(x)
[1] "11.132592"
```