# How to trim white spaces when trimws is not working?

Tags: r

I'm used to use `trimws` to get rid of any blank spaces on text.

Now I've a df that was made with **scraped** data.

I've 2 columns that relate to money but are chr vectors because they where scraped from a web, as mentioned before. To one column I can apply `trimws` with no problem, but not to the other one.

```
str(lacuracao_tvs$precio_actual[1])
chr " 1199.00"
```

**Why?**

```
new_precio_actual <- trimws(lacuracao_tvs$precio_actual[1])

dput(new_precio_actual)
" 1199.00"
```

**trimws works in precio_antes but not in precio_actual:**

```
> str(lacuracao_tvs)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ ecommerce    : chr  "la-curacao" "la-curacao" "la-curacao" "la-curacao" ...
 $ producto     : chr  "TV LED AOC Ultra HD Smart 50\" LE50U7970" "TV Samsung Ultra HD 4K Smart 58\" UN-58RU7100G" "TV LG Ultra HD 4K Smart AI 55\" 55UK6200" "TV AOC Ultra HD 4K Smart 55\" 55U6285" ...
 $ precio_antes : chr  "1899.00" "1899.00" "1899.00" "1899.00" ...
 $ precio_actual: chr  " 1199.00" " 1199.00" " 1199.00" " 1199.00" ...
```

**SessionInfo:**

```
Sys.info()
          sysname           release           version          nodename 
        "Windows"          "10 x64"     "build 17763" "DESKTOP-MNDUKBD" 
          machine             login              user    effective_user 
         "x86-64"       "OGONZALES"       "OGONZALES"       "OGONZALES" 
> sessionInfo(package = NULL)
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.7.8     rvest_0.3.2     xml2_1.2.0      RSelenium_1.7.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0       rstudioapi_0.9.0 bindr_0.1.1      magrittr_1.5    
 [5] rappdirs_0.3.1   tidyselect_0.2.5 R6_2.3.0         rlang_0.3.1     
 [9] stringr_1.3.1    httr_1.4.0       caTools_1.17.1.1 tools_3.5.2     
[13] binman_0.1.1     selectr_0.4-1    semver_0.2.0     subprocess_0.8.3
[17] yaml_2.2.0       openssl_1.1      assertthat_0.2.0 tibble_2.0.1    
[21] crayon_1.3.4     bindrcpp_0.2.2   purrr_0.2.5      bitops_1.0-6    
[25] curl_3.3         glue_1.3.0       wdman_0.2.4      stringi_1.2.4   
[29] compiler_3.5.2   pillar_1.3.1     XML_3.98-1.20    jsonlite_1.6    
[33] pkgconfig_2.0.2
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
utf8ToInt(lacuracao_tvs$precio_actual[1])
[1] 160  49  49  57  57  46  48  48
```

Comment: Could you run utf8ToInt(lacuracao_tvs$precio_actual[1]) and share the output?

Comment: @Katia please, see update 1.

Comment: Yes, That is what I thought. A character with ascii code 160 is not a white space strictly speaking. So that is why you see it as a "blank space" and R does not. trimws only remove the following characters [ \t\r\n]. Let me come up with a code that cleans your character vectors and I will post it soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trimws bug? leading whitespace not removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45050617/trimws-bug-leading-whitespace-not-removed)

Comment: @Katia Where do you find the ascii codes equivalents? I've googled but found pages with up to 126 code.

Comment: @OmarGonzales You can use utf8ToInt(x) function in R to convert your string to a vector with ASCII codes. You can also look at the following link https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl (there are multiple pages), but the codes there are given in hexadecimal format by default. You can press "decimal" on the top of the page to select decimal format

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The character with ASCII code 160 is called a "non-breaking space." One can read about it in Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

The `trimws()` function does not include it in the list of characters that are removed by the function:

```
x <- intToUtf8(c(160,49,49,57,57,46,48,48))
x
#[1] " 1199.00"

trimws(x)
#[1] " 1199.00"
```

One way to get rid of it is by using `str_trim()` function from the *stringr* library:

```
library(stringr)
y <- str_trim(x)
trimws(y)
[1] "1199.00"
```

Another way is by applying `iconv()` function first:

```
y <- iconv(x, from = 'UTF-8', to = 'ASCII//TRANSLIT')
trimws(y)
#[1] "1199.00"
```

**UPDATE**
To explain why trimws() does not remove the "invisible" character described above and stringr::str_trim() does.

Here is what we read from `trimws()` help:

> For portability, ‘whitespace’ is taken as the character class [
> \t\r\n] (space, horizontal tab, line feed, carriage return)

For `stringr::str_trim()` help topic itself does not specify what is considered a "white space" but if you look at the help for `stri_trim_both` which is called by `str_trim()` you will see: `stri_trim_both(str, pattern = "\\P{Wspace}")`
Basically in this case it is using a wider range of characters that are considered as a white space.

**UPDATE 2**

As @H1 noted, version 3.6.0 provides an option to specify what to consider a whitespace character:

> Internally, 'sub(re, "", *, perl = TRUE)', i.e., PCRE library
> regular expressions are used.  For portability, the default
> 'whitespace' is the character class '[ \t\r\n]' (space, horizontal
> tab, carriage return, newline).  Alternatively, '[\h\v]' is a good
> (PCRE) generalization to match all Unicode horizontal and vertical
> white space characters, see also <URL: https://www.pcre.org>.

So if you are using version 3.6.0 or later you can simply do:

```
> trimws(x,whitespace = "[\\h\\v]")
#[1] "1199.00"
```

Comment: May you explain why `str_trim` removes the invisible space and `trimws` not?

Comment: @OmarGonzales Just added some info to my answer. See if this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, Katia. The [\h\v] generalization for matching all space characters is very useful. Don't understand why it is not the standard on trimws()

Answer (score 6):

From R version 3.6.0 `trimws()` has an argument allowing you to define what is considered whitespace which in this case is a no break space.

```
trimws(x, whitespace = "\u00A0|\\s")
[1] "1199.00"
```

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer; use enc2native() and str_trim()

Long Answer; I had a an issue where a database query included non utf-8 encoding text which resulted in the following error.

> Error in sub(re, "", x, perl = TRUE) : input string 5 is invalid UTF-8

I initially used utf8_encode wrapped in an lapply function, however this resulted in all new line and enter characters being replaced with \r & \n which I found undesirable (note, not wrapping it converts the whole df into a character string).

Using enc2native(y) %>% str_trim() avoided this, however to apply it to a df I made a custom function.

```
    cleanDBO <- function(x){
      # Use enc2native as it will replace non utf8 characters with something 
      # readable and not replace \r, \n etc with text.
      x <- x %>% 
        lapply(., function(y) { 
          if(is.character(y)) enc2native(y)  %>% str_trim()
          else y }) %>% as_tibble()
    }
```

This leaves all non-character columns as they are, without the if else all columns are converted to character.